# Enum Int cast to NSNumber - Cannot convert value of type to expected argument type

Tags: swift, enums, nsnumber, swift2

```
public enum ImageType: Int
{
  case Png
  case Jpg
  case Psd

  public init(rawValue: Int)
  {
    switch rawValue {
    case 0:
      self = .Png
    case 1:
      self = .Jpg
    default:
      self = .Psd
    }
  }
}
```

I have public var that I want to have it with an initial value of `NSNumber`

```
public var imageType: NSNumber? = NSNumber(int: ImageType.Psd)
```

but I got an error here `Cannot convert value of type 'ImageType' to expected argument type 'Int32'`

It's strange as I use int for my enum as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The problem

You are using this initializer of `NSNumber`

```
public init(int value: Int32)
```

as you can see it does receive an `Int32`. But you are passing it a `ImageType` so the compiler is not happy and it's telling you exactly that

```
Cannot convert value of type 'ImageType' to expected argument type 'Int32'
```

### The solution

```
public var imageType: NSNumber? = NSNumber(integer: ImageType.Psd.rawValue)
```